# Related objects in reportingviewer 10.0.0.0 give #error

Tags: linq, reportviewer, rdlc

In my VB.net apps i make use of Linq2SQL and Reportviewer with RDLC reports. 
With Visual Studio 2010 they upgraded this reportviewer component so you can use the newer RDL specification from 2008.
Now I've a problem to show related objects. 
For example assume you provide an order to the datasource of the report and then you can show something like  *Fields!Customer.Value.Name*  where Customer is a related entity.

I also got the error in my immediate window:
*Warning: The Value expression for the textrun ‘Name_1.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: The specified operation is not valid.  (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)*

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been reported to Microsoft [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/553592/accessing-nested-objects-in-data-source-of-local-report-does-not-function#) but as yet there is no solution.  The only workaround appears to be exposing the required properties of the related object to the top level object.

Answer (score 0):

A member of the Reporting Services team has [commented](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianhartman/archive/2010/10/27/nested-objects-in-local-mode.aspx) on this issue and explained it's cause and why it's taken so long to get a fix.  The solution has been included in VS2010 SP1, which is currently in beta.